# Google API explorer redirects to https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/#p/

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Note:
I have googled, and read these issues:

[Cannot access API explorer on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706437/cannot-access-api-explorer-on-localhost)

[How to force loading dynamic, insecure content in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058789/how-to-force-loading-dynamic-insecure-content-in-chrome)

and many others but they do not solve my problem.

The problem:

I'm running MacOS and doing my development int Debian VM running in Paralells.
I start up the dev server using the following command:
dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore --host 0.0.0.0 --admin_host 0.0.0.0 app

and I can access the app, endpoints, admin module etc from MacOS using my Debian machine IP eg. http://10.211.55.6:8080/_ah/api/my-service/v1/api etc... everything works fine and as expected except for Google API Explorer.

When I try to access http://10.211.55.6:8080/_ah/api/explorer I am redirected to http://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=http:///10.211.55.6:8080/_ah/api#p/ as expected and I get the ssl error as described in the issue above (again as expected) but then I get redirected a couple of more times and end up at https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/#p/

Note: I cannot click on the lock icon in the title bar because of the redirects

I've tried almost everything I can think of and have google extensively to no avail. Hope someone can help me, I suspect it has something to do with the dev server being run inside of a VM, but I am not sure.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

there is a shield icon in the rightmost part of the address bar that appears when you access the api_explorer locally in chrome. Click and then select load unsafe script and it will load all the service endpoints you define.[loading api_explorer locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjxEy.png)