# Google AppEngine API Explorer redirects and lists no URLs

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-app-engine

I'm having an unending issue trying to use the AppEngine API explorer with the stupidly simple [helloworld](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/hello_world) example.

When trying to navigate to the url to explore the API my Chrome browser redirects to `HTTPS` from the default `HTTP` and no API's are listed. I have gone through every possible fix I can find (Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33956988/2308514), and all of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706437/cannot-access-api-explorer-on-localhost)) and none are working reliably.

What's the most infuriating is I have gotten the API listed **TWICE** but now no longer displays with any of the methods below.

**The setup I had when it worked the first time:**

- Chrome launched with `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe" --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080` (As per the tutorial)
- The url being: (`http://`)`apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=http://localhost:8080/_ah/api&root=http://localhost:8080/_ah/api#p/`

**The second time it worked was using also using the above URL but lasted only a second before being redirected to `HTTPS` and not listing anything.**

Some specifics:

- Windows 10 OS.
- Every time the page loads I get the "*The API you are exploring is hosted over HTTP, which can cause problems. Learn how to use Explorer with a local HTTP API.*" message, even the times the API displayed correctly.
- Every time I now load any of the API Explorer URLs I get redirected to `HTTPS`, and nothing is listed. Also the URL is escaped (`%3A` instead of ':'). Not sure if it's important but the first time it worked the URL was `HTTP` and **NOT** escaped.
- I have tried the shield in the search bar and enabling `Load unsafe scripts` ( from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30768917/2308514)).
- Tried launching Chrome as usual and with the flags `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080` and/or `--allow-running-insecure-content` (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35269406/2308514) answer).
- Tried http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer
- Tried http://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=http://localhost:8080/_ah/api#p/
- http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin works correctly and shows the Admin console every time.

Since the API's being listed once I haven't touched the project code, but restarted the server, Chrome, and tried different URLs on more occasions than I care to count.

I also tried accessing the API URL directly as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17706701/2308514) answer but cannot find the correct URL to access the helloworld `/sayHi` endpoint. Maybe someone can help me work out what I need to prefix it with as all of the variations I try give me a `404`.

Any help would be a *very very* appreciated.

Comment: Hi I have the same problem 
Were you able to find a solution 

I have been trying to myself nothings working for me either.

Comment: @AsadKhan It was a while ago now but I think I eventually just gave up with trying to host it on my local computer. When uploaded to AppEngine it ran okay, and I have just pushed the code to Google's servers everytime I make a change. Not a solution but a workaround that did it for me.