# chrome app and mixed content

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, mixed-content

We're building a HTTPS single page application for internal use. It contains HTTP external links.
If embedded in apk/webview, there's no problem.
If we try on windows workstation, in a browser, we have "mixed content errors". We don't want to add --allow-running-insecure-content to Chrome shortcut.

So my question is , is there a "--allow-running-insecure-content" behavior in Chrome App or Chrome Extension or another way to use our web application?

Thx!

Comment: Have you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058789/how-to-force-loading-dynamic-insecure-content-in-chrome or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321032/how-to-get-chrome-to-allow-mixed-content

Answer (score -1):

Since you cannot modify the **[Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy)** for your chrome packaged app (you may for extensions), you need to use one of several approved methods.

The [**External Content**](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#webview) page has the approved methods and caveats for loading various content including embedding web pages. A basic `webview` syntax is:

```
<webview src="http://news.google.com/" width="640" height="480"></webview>
```

You will also need `"permissions": "webview"` added to your manifest.json.

Comment: well, I've already tried webview  src="https://myapp.com" in a Chrome app. links  or XMLHttpRequest to Http didn't work (mixed content error).